# Zurb Foundaion CLI not recognizing Zurb Stack on basic theme

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am new to Foundation and I am having issues installing blocks through the Foundation CLI. The install doesn't seem to notice the stack and keeps downloading the block as a zip

```
C:\Users\user\site>foundation blocks install sticky-topbar
You don't appear to be in a ZURB stack project, so we can't automatically install building blocks
? Do you want to download as a zip file? No

C:\Users\user\site>dir
Volume in drive C is OS
Volume Serial Number is CABF-C5A0

Directory of C:\Users\user\site

17/06/2019  12:17    <DIR>          .
17/06/2019  12:17    <DIR>          ..
17/06/2019  12:16                63 .gitignore
17/06/2019  12:16                71 CHANGELOG.md
17/06/2019  12:17    <DIR>          css
17/06/2019  12:16    <DIR>          etc
17/06/2019  12:16               974 gulpfile.js
17/06/2019  12:16             7,783 index.html
17/06/2019  12:16    <DIR>          js
17/06/2019  12:16    <DIR>          node_modules
17/06/2019  12:16           256,677 package-lock.json
17/06/2019  12:16               910 package.json
17/06/2019  12:16             1,378 README.md
17/06/2019  12:16    <DIR>          scss
17/06/2019  12:16           171,452 yarn.lock
           8 File(s)        439,308 bytes
           7 Dir(s)  320,466,063,360 bytes free

C:\Users\user\site>
```

How can I correct the problem.

I have all dependencies installed and upgraded to the latest versions, including node.js

I am running Windows 10 pro

Answer (score 1):

The `foundation new` is giving the error

Hence I reinstalled the project with the following and now Foundation CLI version 2.2.5 is recognizing the stack and installing blocks

```
foundation new --framework sites --template zurb
```